Does every set decorate a graph?
Aczel's Antifoundation Axiom $\mathsf{AFA}$ can be formulated as "every graph is decorated by a (unique) set" (well, more specifically, every directed pointed graph or accessible pointed graph). My question is: is the reverse, i.e., "every set decorates a graph" (not necessarily unique, however), immediately true under $\mathsf{ZF}(\mathsf{C})$? If so, is it dependent on Regularity?
I can see how the above statement could be easily proven for wellfounded $\mathsf{ZF}(\mathsf{C})$: Given a set $X$, construct its decorated graph $G_X$ by adding a node for $X$ itself as the root and edges $(x_i, X)$ for each $x_i$ the root of the decorated graph $G_{x_i}$ of each element $x_i$ of $X$. This works quite well precisely due to the wellfounded nature of $\in$ under such a theory.
But what if we are working with an illfounded $\mathsf{ZF}(\mathsf{C})$? Can one still construct (or at least prove the existence of) some such $G_X$ for all $X$? On a related note, are there any complications with regard to the concept of the transitive closure under such an illfounded context?

What does "decorate" mean here?

Yes, just the graph determined by the membership relation (on the set or the set’s transitive closure, depending on what precisely you’re asking). The issue is the opposite: foundation implies there are graphs that have no set decoration (the non-well founded ones).

I think the issue you’re having is that the transitive closure seems connected with foundation somehow, and in weak enough set theories it can be. But given that we have replacement and infinity, it can just be constructed by iterating the union, without needing foundation.

@QiaochuYuan As in, there is some mapping $d$ from the graph's nodes to the set's transitive closure s.t. the set decorates (i.e. is assigned to) the graph's root and each node of the graph is decorated by the set of decorations of its children.

@spaceisdarkgreen Thank you! May I ask precisely how one defines "the graph determined by the membership relation on the set's transitive closure" in $\mathsf{ZFC}$? Indeed, I always thought of the TC as connected with Foundation given the fact that the latter states the inexistence of any $\omega$-length chain of $\in$-relations and the former necessitates only the taking of $\omega$ many unions in order to "show all the set's inner information" (as I conceived it). Thus I stand a tad confused as to how one might picture the TC of a set with, say, $\omega^\omega$-length $\in$-chains...

@Sho There’s an edge pointing from $x$ to $y$ whenever $y\in x$. The membership relation is literally a graph.

@spaceisdarkgreen Yes, I understand that (+ see my previous comment's edit). But (and forgive me if I'm being too dense), isn't that something more external than internal? As in, can I just say, "let $G$ be the graph with $V_G = \mathrm{trcl}(X)$ and $(x, y) \in E_G$ whenever $x \in y$" and that's it? And does such a graph really capture the set's relations when its illfoundedness goes beyond $\omega$-length chains of $\in$'s?

@Sho Membership chains with length $>\omega$ don't really make sense. I mean, I guess you could say you continue an $\omega$-chain $x_0\ni x_1\ni x_2\ni\ldots$ with an $x_\omega$ that is an element of each $x_n$ or something, but that $x_\omega$ already shows up in the transitive closure at an earlier stage.

@Sho And to be clear, you can have these kinds of things (e.g. the accessible pointed graph given by the reverse ordering of $\omega^{\omega}$ with point $0$ has a decoration in AFA), but the whole idea of "accessible" is that everything is connected to the root (in one step in this case).... accessible in infinitely many steps doesn't make sense since there's notion of the 'next' element in a graph after you've gone $\omega$ steps. If you can't get there in finitely many steps, you're not connected to it.

@spaceisdarkgreen Thank you once again! It seems I've got plenty of confusions yet remaining with this topic haha... I was thinking of $>\omega$-length chains of inclusion in the sense of, say, someone grabbing $\aleph_2$ and going with $(x, y)$ whenever $x \in y$ but I suppose that stops working precisely at the limit ordinals... (So I guess I shouldn't worry about $>\omega$-length $\in$-chains?) Thank you for your patience and clear explanation! :)

@Sho Well, as in my previous comment, we can grab $\aleph_2$ and use the reverse membership relation on it as a graph, and get a corresponding set in AFA. I think the problem is you're imagining that $0$ is only pointing at $1$ when it's actually also pointing at e.g. $2$, $\omega+1$ and $\omega_1$ and anything greater than it and so these are all direct elements of the set. A linear order is a transitive relation, so the decorating set is transitive, and the transitive closure is just itself.

@Sho The set is totally ordered by $\ni$ with order type $\omega_2$, though so is a "chain of that length" in that sense. But the idea of a chain in the sense of traversing the membership relation to get at the transitive closure is subtly different from this. And as mentioned, we can just get to any element in one step in this case.
